# Prove that $K’’=1$ for a particular $p$-group $K$

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

Let $S$ be a $p$-group, $N$ a normal subgroup of $S$ contained in $Z(S)\cap S’ $.
Consider $K$, another normal subgroup of $S$ with these two properties:

- $K/K’$ is elementary abelian
- $[K,K,K]=N$

How can I prove, if true, that $K’’=1$?

I tried with some explicit calculation but I can’t find a right strategy.

Comment: $N \le Z(S) \Rightarrow [K,K,K,K] = 1$ but, for all groups $K$ we have $[\gamma_i(K),\gamma_j(K)] \le \gamma_{i+j}(K)$, so $[[K,K],[K,K]] \le [K,K,K,K] = 1$.